# Generating and signing an apk file

Tags: android, apk

i just started coding.
please help he to understand while creating an **apk**. what is **keystore**? what is signed and unsigned? how it would affect my apk. what is **ALIAS**? what to type in that?

Comment: You really should read this before asking something so general: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Read [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here you find all the info on signing your apk for the market :

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @digitalfresh What essential parts would u suggest?